# ArrayList overwriting

Tags: java

I have an ArrayList(called filmes) in which one of the elements is another ArrayList(called actores), this actores is made out of names of actors that have the same movie id as the movie in filmes.
But every time it adds an actor to the actores ArrayList it overwrites the previous one there. 
So when there's more than one actor for the same movie it just shows the last one on the file.

For example the expected output should be 6978 | Big Trouble in Little China | 30-05-1986 [Kurt Russel,Kim Cattrall] [Comedy] but instead it's printing 6978 | Big Trouble in Little China | 30-05-1986 [Kim Cattrall] [Comedy]

```
/*Actorsfile.txt (the last element is the movie id)
11701,Angelina Jolie,false,1995
6384,Keanu Reeves,true,603
7382,Carrie-Anne Moss,false,603
11701,Angelina Jolie,false,10428
6856,Kurt Russell,true,6978
2109,Kim Cattrall,false,6978*/


try{
        File ficheiroA = new File(Actorsfile);
        Scanner leitorFicheiroA = new Scanner(ficheiroA);

        while (leitorFicheiroA.hasNextLine()) {
            ArrayList<Actor> actores = new ArrayList<>();
            Actor actor = new Actor("");
            String linha = leitorFicheiroA.nextLine();
            String dadosA[] = linha.split(",");
            if (dadosA.length == 4) {
                int idFilmeA = Integer.parseInt(dadosA[3]);
                int pos = index(idFilmeA, ids);
                if (idFilmeA == ids[pos]) {
                    actor.nome = (dadosA[1]);
                    actores.add(actor);
                    filmes.get(pos).mudarActores(actores);

                }
            }
        }

    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        String mensagem = "Erro: o ficheiro " + ficheiroActores + " nao foi encontrado.";
        System.out.println(mensagem);
    }
```

Actor Class:

```
public class Actor {
String nome;
String genero;

public Actor(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;


}
public String toString () {
    return nome;
}
}
```

Filme Class:

```
public class Filme {
int id;
String titulo;
ArrayList<Actor> actores= new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<GeneroCinematografico> generos= new ArrayList<>();
String dia,mes,ano;
public Filme(int id, String titulo,ArrayList<Actor> actores, ArrayList<GeneroCinematografico> generos,String ano,String mes,String dia) {
 this.id = id;
 this.titulo = titulo;
 this.actores = actores;
 this.generos = generos;
 this.ano=ano;
 this.mes=mes;
 this.dia=dia;
}


public void mudarId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void mudarTitulo(String titulo) {
    this.titulo = titulo;
}

public void mudarActores(ArrayList<Actor> actores) {
    this.actores =actores;
}

public void mudarGeneros(ArrayList<GeneroCinematografico> generos) {
    this.generos = generos;
}

public String toString() {
    return id + " | " + titulo + " | " + dia + "-" + mes + "-" + ano +" "+ actores +" "+ generos;
}
```

}

Edit:
I've done it a different way and now it's working well in the first filme, but the next are as a null.
Recent output it's 603 | The Matrix | 30-03-1999 [Keanu Reeves, Carrie-Anne Moss] [Science Fiction], 10428 | Hackers | 14-09-1995 null [Action] but the expected is 603 | The Matrix | 30-03-1999 [Keanu Reeves, Carrie-Anne Moss] [Science Fiction], 10428 | Hackers | 14-09-1995 [Angelina Jolie] [Action]. I would be greatful if I could do it this way, without using maps.

```
try{
        File ficheiroA = new File(ficheiroActores);
        Scanner leitorFicheiroA = new Scanner(ficheiroA);
        i=0;
    while (i<ids.length-1) {
        int idFilme=ids[i];
        ArrayList<Actor> actores = new ArrayList<>();
        while (leitorFicheiroA.hasNextLine()) {

            Actor actor;
            String linha = leitorFicheiroA.nextLine();
            String dadosA[] = linha.split(",");
            int idFilmeA = Integer.parseInt(dadosA[3]);
            //int pos = index(idFilmeA, ids);
            if (dadosA.length == 4) {
                if (idFilmeA == idFilme) {
                    actor =new Actor (dadosA[1]);
                    actores.add(actor);
                }
            }
            filmes.get(i).mudarActores(actores);
        }

        i++;
    }
```

Comment: Please give the current output, the rest of the code would help too

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a new ArrayList inside the while, so it is resetting each iteration. What you want to do is to take the creation of the ArrayList outside the while. Instead of:

```
while (leitorFicheiroA.hasNextLine()) {
            ArrayList<Actor> actores = new ArrayList<>();
```

You want:

```
ArrayList<Actor> actores = new ArrayList<>();
while (leitorFicheiroA.hasNextLine()) {
```

And then you call `filmes.get(pos).mudarActores(actores);` when the while finishes.

Edit:

To solve the problem you are commenting, I would remove `filmes.get(pos).mudarActores(actores);` from where it is now. Note that you have all the information you need in each Actor. So,I would leave the logic of the current while as is now, maybe put it in a function readActoresFromFile(), returning the List of Actores. Then I would iterate over each element of the List and put them on a Map which has the filmId as Key and the list of Actors of that film as values. Tell me if you need help with that.

Comment: Like that it's adding every single actor to the ArrayList and printing them all. Like this "6978 | Big Trouble in Little China | 30-05-1986 [Angelina Jolie, Keanu Reeves, Angelina Jolie, Kurt Russell, Kim Cattrall] [Comedy]"

Comment: Edited answer regarding that problem.

Comment: I was trying to do it differently but got a different problem, i edited the post about that.